# Soundcloud embedded via https and some resources responses with 403

Tags: javascript, iframe, soundcloud

This is a two-part question.

**FIRST:**
We're having issues when embedding soundcloud resource, our site uses https.
When an embedded resource is loaded, it makes a request (example url: http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=https://soundcloud.com/user908553597%2Fann-marie-in-my-feelings-treat-me-like-somebody-remake&iframe=true), it is properly responding with this:

```
({
  "version":1.0,
  "type":"rich",
  "provider_name":"SoundCloud",
  "provider_url":"http://soundcloud.com",
  "height":400,"width":"100%",
  "title":"Ann Marie - In My Feelings (Treat Me Like Somebody Remake) by user908553597",
  "description":"",
  "thumbnail_url":"http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000146535766-ycam16-t500x500.jpg",
  "html":"\u003Ciframe width=\"100%\" height=\"400\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F246270367\u0026show_artwork=true\"\u003E\u003C/iframe\u003E",
  "author_name":"user908553597",
  "author_url":"http://soundcloud.com/user908553597"
});
```

However, "provider_url" and "thumbnail_url" is returned with http protocol, as our site is running via https this causes issues.
Is it possible to use a flag or parameter to assure that all resources in the response uses https, or does this require changes in your API ?

**SECOND:**
Some resources seems to return a http 403 response code, example: http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=https://soundcloud.com/richgurl_1%2Ftink-treat-me-like-somebody&iframe=true is this how the API is supposed to handle certain resource requests ? I.e. Is this a predictable behaviour, so that one can act on returned 403`s.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out,
or at least a solution that is managable. Changing the protocol did it
example url: https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=https://soundcloud.com/user908553597%2Fann-marie-in-my-feelings-treat-me-like-somebody-remake&iframe=true

The thumbnail_url is retutrned via http, my solution was to change protocol to https via the .ts file in Angular that takes the response for the above url, using replace. The iframe using the thumbnail_url then has a url with the required protocol.